# cordova 3.4.1 is not working in jelly bean of android

Tags: html, cordova

cordova 3.4.1 is not working in jelly bean  of android and below are the  plugins i used so far

```
"org.apache.cordova.console": "0.2.11",
"org.apache.cordova.device": "0.2.12",
"org.apache.cordova.dialogs": "0.2.10",
"it.mobimentum.phonegapspinnerplugin": "1.1.0",
"hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.SpinnerDialog": "1.2.0",
"org.apache.cordova.camera": "0.3.4",
"org.apache.cordova.file": "1.3.0",
"org.apache.cordova.file-transfer": "0.4.5"
```

the App seems struck and it was not responding

I want  to debug  my App and check what the issue,  i can debug the App in **Kitkat** device using **Gap Debugger** but it is allowing me to debug jelly beam,
can any one tell how to debug my App in **jeally bean**

Answer (score 0):

try remove these two and run your app again.

```
"it.mobimentum.phonegapspinnerplugin": "1.1.0",
"hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.SpinnerDialog": "1.2.0",
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , I removed the two plugins and build the app but the result is same